# Get the output value of system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following method to get the time of the video with ffmpeg do not know what reason I can not put the output of the command

```
command =~ /Duration: ([\d][\d]):([\d][\d]):([\d][\d]).([\d]+)/
```

variable for time and then insert in the
can someone give a help?

```
 def get_time_video

   command = system " ffmpeg -i video.flv 2>&1 "  
   command =~ /Duration: ([\d][\d]):([\d][\d]):([\d][\d]).([\d]+)/  
   time = " #{$1}:#{$2}:#{$3} "  
   puts time    # 00:00:30  
   update_attribute(:time, “#{time}”)  

end
```

Comment: Please surround your code with the 'code' formatting (the block of ones and zeros above the text field). When you output the time, does it give you the correct answer?

Comment: Why aren't you just doing this?

    update_attribute :time, time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Kernel.system` function returns `true` or `false` as seen in the [Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005971).  If you want to parse the output of a command, you can use the backtick notation:

```
system = `ffmpeg -i video.flv 2>&1`
```